# Block about agreement/cookies hides links in the footer

Tags: feature-request, bug, footer

> [image]

Could you add an additional bottom padding/margin for the footer if a block about an agreement appears?

Comment: What for? Why having empty space below it? I find it totally fine the way it is.

Comment: @ShadowWizard is it fine to hide content? o_O

Comment: With a dismissable box that you must read? Yes it is fine and common as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up! This has been very frustrating to me.